# How to implement a conditional validation rule in wpf/XAML

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

I was hoping to find a way to use a custom `ValidationRule` in XAML data binding, but to use it conditionally, such that the rules used are selected dynamically. For my particular problem, I want to validate a physical position range, but that range can either be absolute or relative, depending on a boolean property (bound to a checkbox).

Here is the validation rule I have implemented (the property `Range2Sel` determines which range is used):

```
class IntDualRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int Min1 { get; set; }
    public int Max1 { get; set; }
    public int Min2 { get; set; }
    public int Max2 { get; set; }
    public bool Range2Sel { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult vr = ValidationResult.ValidResult;     
        try
        {
            int num = int.Parse(value.ToString());
            int rangeMin = Range2Sel ? Min2 : Min1;
            int rangeMax = Range2Sel ? Max2 : Max1;
            if (num < rangeMin || num > rangeMax)
            {
                vr = new ValidationResult(false, "The value cannot be less than " + rangeMin + " or greater than " + rangeMax + ".");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            vr = new ValidationResult(false, "The value \"" + value.ToString() + "\" is not a valid integer number.");
        }

        return vr;
    }
}
```

Now I can successfully use this validation rule from C# code, as follows:

```
IntDualRangeRule valInt = new IntDualRangeRule() {
    Min1 = GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_ABS_MIN, 
    Max1 = GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_ABS_MAX, 
    Min2 = GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_REL_MIN,
    Max2 = GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_REL_MAX,
    Range2Sel = Some_Boolean_Property
};
ValidationResult vRes = valInt.Validate(MyTargetPos, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The roadblock I've come up against is how to pull this off in XAML (note the "???"):

```
<Binding Path="GTargetPos" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" Mode="TwoWay" >
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <loc:IntDualRangeRule 
            Min1="{x:Static loc:GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_ABS_MIN}"  
            Max1="{x:Static loc:GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_ABS_MAX}" 
            Min2="{x:Static loc:GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_REL_MIN}"  
            Max2="{x:Static loc:GVars.MTP_GANTRY_TPOS_REL_MAX}" 
            Range2Sel=???
            />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

Binding doesn't work on this kind of parameter, so I have no idea where to go next, or what would be the "best practice" on a problem that surely others have encountered before. In addition to this specific problem, I would also like to know how others deal with validation rules that are only relevant under certain conditions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making Min1 Min2 Max1 Max2 as dependency properties instead of normal properties.